# How to do simple cache file in Flink-Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am new to Flink. I am really confused how to do file caching and load it into a dataset ? I can't find a simple example. I am confused why we need to create a dataset first to call "RichMapFunction" ? How I cache file that with nothing do with any other dataset?  In [sample](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/quick-start-flink-flink-s-broadcast-variable-accumulator-and-distributed-cache.html) I found, it kind of performed join with other dataset. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the case to join two data sets, and one data set is small, use **broadcast** to avoid shuffle. Without broadcasting, it is a pain to shuffle a large data set.

E.g. one dataset has 1 billion records, another one has 100 records. With broadcast, the small dataset will be distributed to all task managers processing those 1 billion records  - no moving 1 billion record for join. Without broadcast, the typical behaviour for joining operation is to shuffle the 1 billion records and 100 records, so that records with same key are in the same machine, which is much more expensive compared to broadcast.

The **RichMapFunction** provides the **open()** method and method to access RuntimeContext. In the open() function, the Flink job can get broadcasted dataset through getRuntimeContext(). getBroadcastVariable(). The open() function is called only **one time** for each operator, so the broadcasted dataset is initialised one time and then it can be applied to all incoming records. That is the reason why to use RichMapFunction() instead of MapFunction().

Note - Broadcast applies to the case that the dataset to broadcast is small. Need to create a dataset first and then broadcast the dataset to all operator. Please refer to [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/dataset/overview/#broadcast-variables) for the usage of the API.

For distributed file caching, it is for the case that the operation(e.g. Map operation) needs to load external file **one time** and use it in the operation.

E.g. A trained model is saved on HDFS. In Flink job, it needs to load the model and apply the model to each record. For this case, the Flink job can use distributed file cache API. The model file will be pulled from HDFS to local machine, and all tasks running on that machine can share the pulled file locally, which saves network and time.

You do not need to create a dataset for the file to be distributed, but using registerCachedFile(). Like the same reason for broadcasting dataset, using RichMapFunction allows the Flink job to load/init distributed file one time.

Please refer to [this document](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/dataset/overview/#distributed-cache) for the usage.